# php ftp_put not working for one directory

Tags: php, ftp

I am using php ftp_connect() and ftp_put() to upload a file from the webserver to an external server.

The code works great when uploading to one directory (in this case /global/1/) but doesn't work when I upload to another one (in this case /{FCADC481-CACAA556A47A}/_schedules/). Therefore I don't think the issue is the code.

The file I am trying to upload is an XML, but I've also tried with .mov and .avi

I have tried both  FTP_ASCII and FTP_BINARY

I have tried with and without ftp_pasv

Both directories and sub directories have the same file access attributes (666)

I can upload to both of these folders using Filezilla directly

The error coming back is:
"Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: ftp_put(): Connection closed; Stream-Lesefehler."

```
$response = false;
$local_file = "/test.xml";                 
$remote_path = "/{".$pov."}/_schedules/";  // NOTE { and } ARE part of the folder name.
$remote_file = $remote_path  .  "test.xml";
if($ftp_conn = ftp_connect($this->ftphost, $this->ftpport,15)){ 
        if (ftp_login($ftp_conn, $this->ftpusr, $this->ftppss)) {               
            ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
            if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
                  $response = true;
            }
        }
}
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
return $response;
```

The only thing I can think is that ftp via PHP doesn't like folders with a "{" symbol. But I have no control over that server, so I have to use it.

I know { can be used in PHP to dechiper a variable value within a string so I tried swapping the symbol for another one and then str_replacing it again afterwards, but it didn'T solve the problem.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Depending on the FTP server software used, `{` and `}` may be used internally for glob patterns. Have you tried escaping those characters (`\\{` and `\\}`)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to escape using backslashes and the error changed to "Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: ftp_put(): Cannot STOR. invalid path!" - regardless of double or single backslashes.   With the backslashes it is trying to upload the file to  /\{FCADC481\}/_schedules/ instead, so I don't think the curly braces are causing escape problems

Comment: UPDATE - actually I don't think the curly braces have anything to do with it. I think the issue is the folder I am trying to upload to is hidden. Is there any way to get around this as I don't have any control over the state of the folder.